# How to get HTML tag After rendering the html on webpage using java or javascript or xslt

Tags: java, javascript, xslt

how to get html source code which was rendered by a javascript in webpage. How can i proceed this? Using xsl or javascript or java.

Comment: context. what do you want to do? What did you try? Where did you look?

Comment: is this for testing proposes by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get entire HTML in current page:

```
function getHTML(){
  var D=document,h=D.getElementsByTagName('html')[0],e;
  if(h.outerHTML)return h.outerHTML;
  e=D.createElement('div');
  e.appendChild(h.cloneNode(true));
  return e.innerHTML;
}
```

outerHTML is non-standard property thus might not supported in some browser (i.e., Firefox), in this case this function mimic the outerHTML feature by cloning the html node into unattached element and read it's innerHTML property.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript provides

```
document.getElementByTagName('')
```

You can get any tag from this line. Moreover if you want to do any operation to this tag then assign any id to that tag. then you can use `document.getElementById('')` to do any operation on it.

These will give you source code.